# set min value to seekbar at runtime in android or custom seekbar to do so

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I am searching code for seekbar minimum value setting at runtime.
taking min value and adding into progress value in progresschanged function will not solve my issue.

My code is having multiple seekbar, second seekbar min value is depend on first seekbar selection value. with adding min value as first seekbar progress value. it is crashing as addition og both was exceeding max value and it is not feasible when i am trying for 6 seekbars.

I have also searched for custom seekbar, where they are providing min and max value setting runtime, but i didnot find progress value.

I didnot understand how google left such widget.Please let me know if any solution is there.
In my requirement max value is fix and min value varies based on previos seekbar selection.

Comment: Post what you have tried

Comment: int Min=20;

                progressChangedValue = Min+progress;

                t.setText(""+progressChangedValue);

                if(progressChangedValue2<progressChangedValue) {
                    simpleSeekBar2.setProgress(simpleSeekBar.getProgress());
                }

Answer (score 1):

Please find the [library](https://github.com/syedowaisali/crystal-range-seekbar) for custom seek bar.It provides different types of seek bar.
You can change bar value programatically using

```
rangeSeekbar.setMinStartValue(float minValue).apply();
```

and

```
rangeSeekbar.setMinStartValue(float minValue).setMaxStartValue(float maxValue).apply();
```

Comment: Thanks, I just wanted min value setting at runtime, i will try and let you know if any issue.

Comment: I am trying  to open code in android studio , but it hangs on building gradle project, till now i have tried 2-3 times.

Comment: Add a dependency to your build.gradle:

`dependencies {
    compile 'com.crystal:crystalrangeseekbar:1.1.1'
}`

Comment: not working, cannot graddle in android studio, currently using 2.2.3 version

Comment: its not opening...when you open project ,its hang on

Comment: add crystalrangeseekbar folder in your project by importing it as module then you will be able to use it.
ideally it should not hang because i have used it.it is working perfectly in my project

Comment: I have added with a module, but it was giving an error. So , I have added this line in Gradle compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['crystal-range-seekbar-master'])

Comment: now, the code is working, but my basic requirement is not achieved. I need min value and progress value both need to set runtime. now, when I change min value it will not allow me to go back to previous value. means if I set min value from 5 to 10, at runtime i cannot go from 10 to 5.

Comment: I need Min value and progress value changing runtime

Comment: i am not getting your problem please explain

Comment: I was using 6 seek bars and trying to set min value of slider 2 based on current value of seek bar 1. all next seek bar including seeking bar 3 to 6 need to set its mean value based on seek bar1.  I have found the solution, as I have solved this problem with checking both sliders value in their value changed function

Comment: Great ! Don't forget to up vote my answer if it helped you.